# FullCalendar Angular multiple events

Tags: angular, typescript, events, fullcalendar

I would like to program an appointment calendar with FullCalendar with Angular (Typescript). I would like to read several events from the database and also display them in color in the calendar. I don't know how to display multiple events on the screen? So far I can only add one event, but I want to show all of them. Can this be done with a field?

Comment: Could you share how is going your code so far?

Comment: buchung.forEach((b1: Buchung) =>
    {
      console.log("B1:"+b1.m_id+" Datum: "+b1.datum);

      this.eventData.push({
        title: ''+b1.m_id,
        date: b1.datum
      });

      /*
      this.eventData = [ this.eventData,
        {
          title: ''+b1.m_id,
          date: b1.datum
        }
      ];

       */
    });

Comment: @Input() eventData: any = [{title: 'Test01', date: new Date('2022-08-26')}];

Comment: calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
     locale: 'de',
     plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
     initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
     firstDay: 1,
     editable: true,
     selectable: true,
     selectMirror: true,
     dayMaxEvents: true,
     eventColor: "#64B32C",
     events: this.eventData,

Comment: You could show multiple events just passing to the `events` property of `CalendarOptions`. If the events are fetched from the `db` you have to ensure to map this data to the expected from full-calendar

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you have code or other updates. It's much easier to read that way

Comment: `[{title: 'Test01', start: new Date('2022-08-26')}, { title: "test02", start: "2022-08-27" }]`. That's two events in an array. It's not really clear where the problem is. You must use "start" instead of "date", fullcalendar doesn't (officially) recognise "date" as a valid event property.